# How to select first/default <option> value in Modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm adding data from my modal to database, and after data is added I would like to reset dropdown values in my modal

And here is code of these dropdowns:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label dash-control-label col-sm-3" for="">Tax:</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<select id="taxSelect" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity">
  <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
  <option *ngFor="let tax of taxes" [value]="tax.id">
    {{tax.title}}
  </option>
</select>
</div>

<label class="control-label dash-control-label col-sm-3" for="">UoM:</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<select id="unitOfMeasureSelect" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity">
  <option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
  <option [value]="um.id" *ngFor="let um of unitOfMeasures">{{um.title}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see guys, default value for my dropdown is

```
<option disabled [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
```

So I'm wondering how can I after submit and closing this modal, reset these option/dropdown values to default state again (to this value: "-/-")..

Right now when dropdown is touched, and if it's opened again it's gonna show previous selected value and I want to avoid that...

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use in method submit `$('#taxSelect').val(null)`

Answer (score 0):

simply use ngModel directive on the select node and bind it to a variable. and set the value to null after data has been submitted. btw: how do you read the selected value without ngModel at the moment?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedUnit">
    <option [ngValue]="null">-/-</option>
    <option [value]="um.id" *ngFor="let um of unitOfMeasures">{{um.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Typescript code may look like this:

```
export class MyFormComponent {

    public selectedUnit: any = null;

    constructor() {}

    public submitForm(form: NgForm): void {
        //do some server call
        this.selectedUnit = null; // set selectedUnit to null so the dropdown value will change
    }
}
```

you'll need to import FormsModule into your App

Comment: @A.Winner yeah I'm reading it without ngModel because select2 won't allow me to use ngModel to get data from my <option> (I'll post code of that later), can you post also typescript code how that might looks?

Comment: i added some typescript code. It is really just assigning null to the bound variable after submitting data. If it does not work, please post more of your code.